# How do I print DIV content of HTML to printer with Javascript only?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I needed to print the content of HTML div. For that I have added a button. I am trying to call a function onclick of button to print the div content using Javascript.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can add an id to the div and use: `printWindow.document.write(document.getElementById("yourId").innerHtml)`

Comment: This will print all the div elements, What the OP wants is to print the content of the div, i.e the innerHtml or more like the innerText of the div. So  this will not work here.

Comment: This will work: 
printWindow.document.write(document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].innerHtml)

Comment: We're not sure whether OP needs the content of first div. Confirm with him and update your answer :)

Comment: He can add an id to the div and use: printWindow.document.write(document.getElementById("yourId").innerHtml)

Comment: That's possible. Update your answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample code to print a div on button click.

```
<body>
<div id='printarea'>
    <p>This is a sample text</p>
</div>
<button onclick="print()">Print</button>
</body>

<script>
function print() {
    var divToPrint = document.getElementById('printarea');
    var htmlToPrint = '' +
        '<style type="text/css">' +
        'table th, table td {' +
        'border:1px solid #000;' +
        'padding;0.5em;' +
        '}' +
        '</style>';
    htmlToPrint += divToPrint.outerHTML;
    newWin = window.open("");
    newWin.document.write("<h3 align='center'>Print Page</h3>");
    newWin.document.write(htmlToPrint);
    newWin.print();
    newWin.close();
}
</script>
```